# How to solve the previously saved signature issue?

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, pdflib

I'm using Lazypdf kit library.

My problem is when we open a new pdf from the tableview it shows the previously signed signature . I want to clear the signature which comes at every pdf?

The library can be found on [github](https://github.com/lazyprogram/LazyPDFKit).

Comment: Welcome to SO :-) What have you tried to do? How does your code look like? (Please do edit the question, do not add interesting details by commenting)